# Firefox Intermediate CA does not update, need to debug by exporting all certificates and import on another instance

Tags: windows, firefox

We are troubleshooting a certificate issue on a Firefox browser.

The SSL certificate bundle on the web server contains a new intermediate certificate valid till 2032, however, on a work computer, the Firefox browser shows the website URL as valid in certification, but intermediate certificate still stays as the old one valid till 2025.

The SSL certificate chain is the company's self-signed, and the Firefox browser on the work computer is also managed by the company's IT.

The same issue does not happen on a freshly installed testing virtual machine: once import the company's self-signed Root CA, the website's URL correctly shows the intermediate certificate as valid till 2032.

On the same physical work computer, the issue does not happen on Chrome either.

So, we suspect the issue is due to either:

- The company's configuration, or
- Some of our past tests on the work computer.

So, we want to export all of the SSL certificates from the Windows 10 work computer, and then import them to the testing Firefox instance on the virtual machine.

**Our Question:**

- How to export all the certificates, in X.509 (.CER) format?